# Implementing a Dynamic Filterable Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

#### Details:

I'm currently working on building a carousel with bootstrap, and I'm facing some challenges in making it display correctly. Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

- Initially, the carousel is empty.
- Upon clicking a button (which would act like a filter), I want to populate the carousel with divs that contain images. When a button is clicked (e.g., "cars"), only images of cars should be added to the carousel. Clicking a button labeled "all" should add all available images to the carousel.

#### Requirements:

- Display four tiles at a time in the carousel.
- I want the dynamic carousel to respond similarly to the normal carousel, rotating through all entities. For example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3... etc.
- Add elements to the carousel based on the button clicked.

#### What i have tried:

I have a functioning normal carousel that you can find here: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ToasterGhost/uvzestyL/8/)
HTML:

```
<!--Carousel-->
<div class="desktop-carousel">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=1" loading="lazy" onerror="imgError()">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=2" loading="lazy">
                <p class="name items">Self care</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=3" loading="lazy">
                <p class="name items">Pain</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=4" loading="lazy">
                <p class="name items">Self care</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5">
              <a href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=5" loading="lazy">
                <p class="name items">Hepilor</p>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-dark w-auto" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next bg-dark w-auto" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Carousel //

$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2500
});

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
  var minPerSlide = 4;
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

However, I'm struggling to make the dynamic carousel work as intended.
Here is a link to it: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ToasterGhost/68qg3zcx/8/)
HTML:

```
<button id="addItemButton" onclick="filterSelection()">Add Items to Carousel</button>

<button id="clearCarousel" onclick="clearCarousel()">Clear Items From Carousel</button>

<div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox"></div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        Previous
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        Next
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Create Carousel //
function filterSelection() {
  var carouselData = [{
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=1",
      name: "Hannon"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=2",
      name: "Self care"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=3",
      name: "Pain"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=4",
      name: "Self care"
    },
    {
      imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/272x192?text=5",
      name: "Hepilor"
    }
  ];

  var carouselInner = $('.carousel-inner');
  var count = 0;
  // Add items to carousel
  carouselData.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (count == 0) {
      console.log('Inside If');
      var isActive = (index === 0) ? "active" : "";
      var itemHtml = `
      <div class="carousel-item ${isActive}">
        <div class="carousel-item-content col-lg-3 col-md-5">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="${item.name}">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;
      carouselInner.append(itemHtml);
    } else {
      console.log('In Else')
      var isActive = (index === 0) ? "active" : "";
      var itemHtml = `
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="carousel-item-content col-lg-3 col-md-5">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="${item.imageUrl}" alt="${item.name}">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;
      carouselInner.append(itemHtml);
    }
    count++;
  });

  // Initialize the carousel
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
}


// Run carousel //
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 1500
});

$('.carousel .carousel-item').each(function() {
  var minPerSlide = 4;
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i = 0; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    next = next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});

function clearCarousel() {
  $('.carousel-inner').empty();
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('dispose');
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, alternative approaches, solutions, or guidance you can provide.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question, please do not just dump the whole thing on external platforms like jsfiddle.

Comment: What are you using as a filter? And does the order matter? e.g. if choosing everything that is red and everything that is blue do all the reds need to be together and then all the blues or doesn't it matter?

Comment: @AHaworth I use buttons as a filters. The buttons should call the function and then pass a parameter telling it the filter requirement like 'cars'. Not exactly sure what you meant, but it should just push all divs that meet the criteria to the carousel.

Comment: @Yogi Oh, sorry, thought things like angular, react was considered frameworks, thought bootstrap was considered a library. Should i remove that part?

Comment: What I want to know is how you store the info about type. Is that name in the object?

Comment: I first tried something like this:
```HTML
<div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
```
Now i would technically use the name yes:
```JavaScript
var carouselData = [
    {
      imageUrl: "images/image_1.jpg",
      name: "Hannon"
    },
```
I haven't implemented the filter yet, but if i can make the carousel rotate properly, then i  feel like the filtering part should be fairly straight forward. I added all my thoughts in case there is a better way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple carousel that shows one item at a time that works with filters. The filters are easy to understand and work with (adding more filters and/or modifying existing ones). You can expand it to show more than one element if needed.

```js
const cars = [
  "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/3KmYR/s4/genesis-g80-exterior.webp",
  "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/yM93o/s4/honda-civic-type-r-exterior.webp",
  "https://cdn.motor1.com/images/mgl/KjMYQ/s4/bugatti-divo-exterior.webp"
];

const buildings = [
  "https://ychef.files.bbci.co.uk/1280x720/p0db81jf.jpg",
  "https://ychef.files.bbci.co.uk/1600x900/p0db827c.webp"
];

const dogs = [
  "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=0.752xw:1.00xh;0.175xw,0&resize=1200:*",
  "https://publish.purewow.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/06/smallest-dog-breeds-toy-poodle.jpg?fit=728%2C524",
  "https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/images/pets/cute-dog-headshot.jpg?_=42445",
  "https://www.thetimes.co.uk/imageserver/image/%2Fmethode%2Ftimes%2Fprod%2Fweb%2Fbin%2Fc47f6830-9292-11ed-b04f-b9bf191ef388.jpg?crop=5879%2C3919%2C0%2C0"
];

const filters = {
  all: [...cars, ...buildings, ...dogs],
  cars,
  buildings,
  dogs
};

const carousel = document.getElementById("carousel");
const carouselNavigation = document.getElementById("carouselNavigation");

function selectFilter(button) {
  button.parentElement.querySelector(".active")?.classList.remove("active");
  const filter = button.getAttribute("value");
  button.classList.add("active");

  carousel.innerHTML = "";
  carouselNavigation.innerHTML = "";

  const thisFilterElementsNumber = filters[filter].length - 1;

  filters[filter].forEach((url, index) => {
    carousel.innerHTML += `
      <div id="carouselSlide${index}" class="carouselSlide">
        <div class="carouselSnapper"></div>
        <a href="#carouselSlide${index === 0 ? thisFilterElementsNumber : (index - 1)}" class="carouselPrev"></a>
        <a href="#carouselSlide${index === thisFilterElementsNumber ? 0 : (index + 1)}" class="carouselNext"></a>
        <img src="${url}">
      </div>
    `;

    carouselNavigation.innerHTML += `<a href="#carouselSlide${index}" class="carouselNavigationButton"></a>`;
  });
}

selectFilter(document.querySelector(`[value="all"]`));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}


/* Filter */

.filters {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.filterButton {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 999px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.filterButton.active {
  background-color: #111111;
}


/* Carousel */

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  perspective: 100px;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after,
.carouselPrev,
.carouselNext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  border-radius: 999px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel::before,
.carouselPrev {
  left: 10px;
}

.carousel::after,
.carouselNext {
  right: 10px;
}

.carousel::before,
.carousel::after {
  content: "";
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #222222;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='0,50 80,100 80,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 100 100' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,50 20,100 20,0' fill='%23fff'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carouselViewport {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.carouselSlide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.carouselSnapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.carouselNavigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.carouselNavigationButton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #222222;
  border-radius: 999px;
  transition: transform 0.1s;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <p class="filterButton" onclick="selectFilter(this);" value="all">All</p>
  <p class="filterButton" onclick="selectFilter(this);" value="cars">Cars</p>
  <p class="filterButton" onclick="selectFilter(this);" value="buildings">Buildings</p>
  <p class="filterButton" onclick="selectFilter(this);" value="dogs">Dogs</p>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carouselViewport" id="carousel"></div>
  <div class="carouselNavigation" id="carouselNavigation"></div>
</div>
```